# Fetch .jsx file from AWS s3 bucket in react

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I am currently fetching dynamic pages lazily as shown below. How can I import the .jsx file from AWS S3 or CloudFront instead?

```
    const importPost = (id) =>
      lazy(() =>
        import(`../../posts/Post_${id}.jsx`).catch(() =>
          import(`../../posts/Not_Found`)
        )
      );
```

Comment: If the files are public, you just link to the direct object link. What have you tried?

Comment: Yeah, the files are public. I tried just passing the s3 object url into the import, but react can't resolve it.

Comment: Does it work with remote files in general? Or is this only with S3?

Comment: I have only tried s3, but I'm pretty sure its not a s3 issue.